# Testing that Sidekiq received correct delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sidekiq, rspec-sidekiq

Inside of my User model I'm calling a delayed method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.import_items
    ...
    User.delay.keep_only_user_cars(1) # "1" is just for testing
  end
end
```

And I'm trying to test it like so (using [rspec-sidekiq](https://github.com/philostler/rspec-sidekiq) gem):

```
expect(Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass).to have_enqueued_job("keep_only_user_cars", 1)
```

This is what I get:

```
Failure/Error: expect(Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass).to have_enqueued_job("keep_only_user_cars", 1)
  expected to have an enqueued Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass job with arguments ["keep_only_user_cars", 1] but none found
  found: [["---\n- !ruby/class 'User'\n- :keep_only_user_cars\n- - 1\n"]]
```

Which basically works, just has a bit different formatting.

How do I fix this test to make sure that Sidekiq received exactly this method with exactly this attribute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-Extensions#troubleshooting), the delay extensions send the entire object in redis, not just the values. If you want to test for that object, you'd need to use YAML.dump(object):

```
expected = YAML.dump([User,:keep_only_user_cars,1])
expect(Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass).to have_enqueued_job(expected)
```

Comment: Saved my day :) The only fix: I found that method args have to be in array: `expected = YAML.dump([User,:keep_only_user_cars,[1]])`